# List of citations doesn’t get recognized by SDTT

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, citations

I am trying to structure a list of citations properly using JSON-LD and just cannot get Google’s SDTT to recognize the items.

I have simplified the data here.  Can anyone tell me what it is that is not allowing the SDTT to see the item?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "ItemList" {
        "@type": "citation" {
            "@type" : "periodical" {
                "name": "Log of Mystic Seaport (1948-2003; Vols. 1-54)"
             },
    "@type": "vehicle" {
        "name": "Mary Celeste",
        "category": "brig",
        "date": "1905",
        "nationality": "American",
        "weight": "",
        "id": ""
      }
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried verifying that your json-ld is valid? Have you tried testing it using the tool which google uses for structured data?  Also would suggest you check that your schema is valid for schema.org.

Comment: You have four `{` and five `}`. -- About your code formatting: You don’t need to write `< script` and `< /script` to display the markup in a code block. Enclosing your markup in "`" is only needed for inline code, but you are using a code block.

Comment: Yeah, the single quotes were a mistake in pasting.  It is "detected, but the items found remains 0, so I assume there is something wrong. It is close to schema.org, but not exact.  Perhaps that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Errors

In JSON-LD, the curly braces always have to come in pairs:

- You have four `{`, but five `}`.

Schema.org terms are case-sensitive:

- There is no `periodical`, but [`Periodical`](https://schema.org/Periodical).
- There is no `vehicle`, but [`Vehicle`](https://schema.org/Vehicle).

JSON-LD’s `@type` can only be used for types, not for properties:

- [`citation`](https://schema.org/citation) is not a type, but a property.

A `@type` statement can’t be followed by a `{`:

- `"@type": "ItemList" {` (and the other occurrences) is invalid. It seems that you want to use a property here in addition.

For a Schema.org type, you should only use properties that are defined for it:

- The [`Vehicle`](https://schema.org/Vehicle) type doesn’t define the properties `date`, `nationality`, nor `id` (there is no such property in Schema.org).

#### `ItemList` entries

You need to use the [`itemListElement`](https://schema.org/itemListElement) property for providing the list entries:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "CreativeWork"
    },
    {
      "@type": "CreativeWork"
    },
    {
      "@type": "CreativeWork"
    }
  ]
}
```